# Jmeter: How to run some thread group together and some thread groups consecutively?

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, group

I am creating a test plan in which I create a user under this user I have to create multiple orgs(consider it as sub user). Now I want to send 1000 request each seconds divided by the orgs created. How can I achieve this?

So far, for this I created one user in a thread group, then I created another thread group for creating orgs and shooting events, problem is only one request goes per org created. If I put a loop controller I would get events one after another, but I want to achieve the higher TPS and want to hit the backend with atleast 1000 TPS.

1. Can I define few thread to run consecutively and few to run parallel in single Jmeter Plan?
2. Can I define the Thread Group on run time depending on how many orgs(Sub Users) I create?

I also need to keep a track of all the sub users and modify their values as needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you can have either consecutive or parallel thread groups execution. There is [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) which may help you in generating the pre-requisites
2. You can configure Thread Group to run forever and then conditionally stop the test using [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) and [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler combination

Comment: Thanks for replying, I will try using setUp Thread Group see if that works.